# Is this kind of listing okay?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, articles

I am stuck with using the articles.

In the sentence:

> I was employed as: declarant, interviewer, promoter, boutique seller.

Do I use an article only after *as* or in front of each word? Can I omit it anyway?

P.S. Is *declarant* correct word in English for a person who puts/adheres declarations on products that go on sale?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "declarant" and "declarations"? Are you talking about someone who adheres labels to goods? I don't think I've ever head a word for the role of someone who performs this task.

Comment: @Tashus I do not know how exactly the terms are expressed in English, but yes, I am talking about that person.

Comment: Is there a specific word for this in your native language? If so, what are the language and the word?

Comment: @Tashus In Serbian we say _deklarant_, but maybe in English exist some phrase if there is no word, I don't know

Comment: I can't think of a specific word or phrase for this task, but I have never worked in retail. You may simply have to describe the role or task in a few words. "Inventory manager" sounds better than "label placer".

Comment: "Product Labeler" does not sound nearly as nice as "Inventory Manager"  - agreed here.  And your as usage sounds ok, but I might use "I was employed as an Inventory Manager, Interviewer, Promoter, and as a Botique Seller."

Comment: @Tashus - That may sound better, but it could also be misleading. It could be that the OP worked for an inventory manager while placing labels on goods, but the responsibilities of an [inventory manager](https://www.snagajob.com/job-descriptions/inventory-manager/) go much deeper than that.

Comment: @J.R. Good point. That was the closest "role" I could think of for the task described. How about "Sticker Sticker"? (That's a joke in case it isn't clear.)

Comment: @Tashus - That's a funny joke! As for what the role would formally be called, I think we'd need to know more about the job. What kinds of labels and what information was on them? And where did this happen? I mean, I can imagine anything from inventory control labels on a factory floor to price tags in the aisle of a store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically correct either to use only a single article before the first noun or to use an article before every noun. I would recommend using the article before every noun if you would like to emphasize that you were employed in several roles (whether or not these were at the same time) and to use the article only before the first noun if you would like to emphasize that you were employed in one multifaceted role.

I would also not recommend using a colon, as this is a rather simple list. Instead, you can simply write "I was employed as a declarant..."

I am not quite sure what you mean, but I do not believe "declarant" is used in this way in English. (Instead it has a [specific legal meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarant).)